# $f \in C^1((a,b))$ can be extended to a function in $C^1([a,b])$ provided one-sided limits of $f'$ exist at $a$ & $b$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be defined and $C^{1}$ on $(a,b)$, and suppose one-sided limits of $f'$ exist at $a$ and $b$. I have to prove that one-sided limits of $f$ exist at $a$ and $b$ and $f$ can extended to a $C^1$ function on $[a,b]$.

But I can't make heads or tails out of this, can I get some help?

This is 7.5.5, Problem 12 in Way of Analysis by Strichartz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c := \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$. It is sufficient to show that

(a) $f(a) := \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and

(b) $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = c$.

As to (a) we first see that $f$ is Lipschitz on $(a,b)$: By the mean value theorem, if $x,x'\in (a,b)$, then there exists $y\in (x,x')$ such that $f(x)-f(x') = f'(y)(x-x')$. But $|f'|$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and thus has a maximum $L$. So, $|f(x)-f(x')|\le L|x-x'|$. Thus, if $x_n\to a$, then $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\le L|x_n-x_m|$ shows that $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence converges to some $d$. Let $(x_n')$ be any sequence with $x_n'\to a$. Then $|f(x_n')-f(x_n)|\le L|x_n-x_n'|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So, also $f(x_n')\to d$. But that means that indeed $f(a) := \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.

(b): Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f'(x)-c|<\epsilon$. Let $|x-a|<\delta$ and choose $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to a$. Then
\begin{align}
f(x)-f(a)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x)-f(x_n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f'(\xi_n)(x-x_n)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}(f'(\xi_n)-c)(x-x_n) + c(x-a),
\end{align}
where $\xi_n\in (x_n,x)$. Hence,
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - c\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|f'(\xi_n)-c|\frac{x-x_n}{x-a}\le\epsilon.
$$
This implies the claim.